# How to create few url in one controller use .net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I work with ASP .NET core, and I have issues.

I have 3 pages which can be created in one controller, but for this pages I **must have just one controller** and in this conroler, I must have a function which will create **separate URL** for this **3 pages**.

For example:

*http://mydomain/page/***Home, Load, Blog;**

For this, I need have navigation, but I will have the same **HTML file** only will data change from the model.

So I will have 3 navigation button which will navigate user for **same page** but another content which I will receive from the model, and from controller I just need change page URL.

How I can do this?

Comment: Actually, generally that's not the way to go. You should be creating different controllers for different pages (generally speaking). Each controller named as 'PageNameController' with an index Action inside of it that leads to returning the view. Is there a specific reason why you need them all in one controller?

Comment: @Jabberwocky for this i not need to create separate controllers and index pages, because i wil copie past code, i have same view at 3 pages

Comment: "for this pages I must have just one controller" ...why? That seems like a totally arbitrary requirement which goes against the general principles of MVC. " i have same view at 3 pages" ...I don't see how that has any impact on your use of controllers.

Comment: @qunz666 you're going against what MVC is standing for. If you have the same view and the same content then return the view with the model you need from the appropriate controller. MVC is all about separation of concerns and you're planning on doing the opposite.

Comment: @Jabberwocky so for this maybe i can create 3 controllers, and just use only one HTML page, this is possible?

Comment: @qunz666 Yes. You have to study the basics of MVC. Naming conventions so .NET knows how to map your controllers to your view. Your model is going to be your content. and the view will inherit it from the controller if you tell it to.

Comment: you can create a single controller with single action. Decorate that action with `[Route("page/{pageName")]` and add `string pageName` parameter to this action.

Comment: @vasily.sib can u provide some example?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to repeat the HTML? Use one view. And then you can have a controller like this snippet:

```cs
class PagesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("about")]
    public IActionResult About() => View("MyCommonView", yourModel); // get the model from wherever you plan to

    [HttpGet("contact")]
    public IActionResult Contact() => View("MyCommonView", yourModel);

    [HttpGet("whateverelse")]
    public IActionResult WhateverElse() => View("MyCommonView", yourModel);
}
```

It's possible to just have one action, but I wouldn't do that. I'd instead have separate views per action, and put the markup that's common for the three actions layout file. That will give the different actions more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

One of the way is to decorate your action with `Route` attribute:

```
[Route("page")]
public class PagesController : Controller
{
    // you may also use [HttpGet("{pageName}", Name = "PagePath")] instead,
    // to explicitly match HTTP GET requests
    [Route("{pageName}", Name = "PagePath")]
    public IActionResult GetPage(string pageName)
    {
        switch(pageName?.ToLower())
        {
            case "home":
                return View("Page", homeModel);
            case "home":
                return View("Load", loadModel);
            case "home":
                return View("Blog", blogModel);
            default:
                return NotFound();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can create your view at `Views/Pages/Page.cshtml` and generate links with helpers:

```
@Url.RouteUrl("PagePath", new { pageName = "Home" }) <!-- will produce "/page/Home" string -->
```